# Update a record after it is processed using MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am inserting records from a table that has a column IsMatch.  I have written an insert statement that works but I have run into a slight catch.

My insert record only selects the top 1 from the table where IsMatch = 2.

I need to update the record after it is inserted so that IsMatch = 3 and thus it will not be selected again.

Here is the code:

```
begin tran

INSERT INTO [Contact](
 [Company]
 , [Contact]
 , [Title]
 , [MailingAddress]
 , [MailingCity]
 , [MailingState]
 , [MailingZip]
 , [ShippingAddress]
 , [ShippingCity]
 , [ShippingState]
 , [ShippingZip]
 , [Phone]
 , [SIC]
 , [EmpSize]
 , [LockedBy]
 , [LastUpdated]
 , [Source]
 , [CreateDate]
 , [ContactCategory]
 , [ContactGroup]
 , FirstName
 , LastName
 , Mar
 , website
)
SELECT top 1 
   company
   , firstname+ ' ' + lastName as contact
   , contactTitle as title
   , address as mailingaddress
   , city as mailingcity
   , state as mailingstate
   , zip as mailingzip
   , locationaddress as shippingaddress
   , locationcity as shippingcity
   , locationstate as shippingstate
   , locationzip as shippingzip
   , phone
   , primarysic as sic
   , employeeSizeRange as empsize
   , 0 as lockedby
   , '2015-01-19' as lastUpdated
   , 'InfoUSA20141231' as source
   , getdate() as createdate
   , 'Cellular Telephones-Service & Repair' as contactCategory
   , 'InfoUsa' as ContactGroup
   , lastName
   , firstname
   , 'PB-NewWireless' as Mar
   , website
FROM  tmp_WirelessRepairListDec2014 
WHERE isMatch = 2

UPDATE tmp_WirelessRepairListDec2014 
SET    isMatch = 3 
WHERE  id in (
       SELECT top 1 id 
       FROM   tmp_WirelessRepairListDec2014 
       WHERE isMatch = 2
)

commit tran
```

Comment: Can you post the `INSERT` query and maybe some sample data which you are having problems with?

Comment: Change the value during insert? You didn't provide any kind of details here for anybody to have much to go on.

Comment: If you add the same ORDER BY clause to both the insert and update, it looks like it should work.

Comment: Do not use `SELECT TOP 1`. If multiple threads execute that code at the same time, you may update the wrong record(s). Instead, use something like the approach mentioned in [the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28028671/104223)

Comment: Though, if it is the *same* record you just inserted, is there a reason you can't just insert a hard coded "3" in your INSERT?  (BTW, if formatting is an issue, you don't have to include the entire statement. Just the key fields, ie enough to give the gist of what you are doing.)

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
DECLARE @tempTable as TABLE 
( 
    pkid bigint null
)

INSERT INTO TABLENAME
(
    COL1,
    COL2,
    COL3
)

OUTPUT INSERTED.pkid
INTO @tempTable 
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3
FROM TABLENAME_2
```

Now you can use the PKID value in the @tempTable to update your record

`SELECT * FROM @tempTable`